# Cakephp Routing

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-1.3

I want that users can surf to http://www.yyy.com/xxx for xxx being a parameter. and so with www.yyy.com/xxx/zzz . I have following routing which works fine:

```
Router::connect('/:town', array('controller'=>'places', 'action'=>'index'), array('pass' => array('town')));
Router::connect('/:town/:category', array('controller'=>'places', 'action'=>'index'), array('pass' => array('town', 'category')));
```

But when I want tot surf to a different controller example www.yyy.com/differentcontroller/add it goes back to the places controller unless I make a routing for it...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The second rule on your routing list is simply looking for two sets of any combinations of characters after the domain name and treating the first as a town and the second as a category.  As a result it mistakenly parses 'differentcontroller' as a town name and 'add' as a category.  If you want to keep this URL structure then you'll need to add more specific routes to your routing file to cover situations like the 'add' route, or consider changing your existing URL layout to something more specific, like:

```
Router::connect('/places/:town', array('controller'=>'places', 'action'=>'index'), array('pass' => array('town')));
Router::connect('/places/:town/:category', array('controller'=>'places', 'action'=>'index'), array('pass' => array('town', 'category')));
```

Comment: Hi I'm defining explicit routes for my other controllers now but the problems is that when I want to link to my original places using the Html helper and it's link method it does not do the routing as I want it to be.

echo $this->Html->link(__('View', true), array('action' => 'view', $place['Address']['town'],$place['Place']['category']));

will route me to http://www.yyy.com/places/view/Town/Category instead of http://www.yyy.com/Town/Category

Answer (score 0):

My memories about cake routing is quite rusty, but you can use :controller/:action as a rule to make cake look for a valid controller/action pair, if I remember correctly.